# Query on migrating a azure mobile service to azure app service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-mobile-services

A newbie to this. I have a requirement to migrate a mobile service in the classic portal to new azure app services in the new portal.

Few questions pertaining to this:-

1) The classic portal having the mobile service has some scheduled jobs. Where can I see the jobs in the new portal once migrated ?

Since I have only the production instance to work with, I do not want to take any chance, so my plan is to create new Scheduled job service within the "App services" in the new portal exactly the same as in the old portal. Will this suffice ?

2) The classic portal has a mobile service with a name. if I do not want to press the "Migrate to app service" button, is there a way to create the same service with the same name in the new portal(as a app service). what type should we create. A mobile app or web app ?

Also, How can I create scheduled jobs within the new app service.

Answer (score 0):

From the document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-migrating-from-mobile-services

All scheduler jobs are available through the Scheduler Job Collections section. To access your scheduler jobs:

- Log in to the Azure portal.
- Select Browse>, enter Schedule in the Filter box, then select Scheduler Collections.
- Select the Job Collection for your site. It is named sitename-Jobs.
- Click Settings.
- Click Scheduler Jobs under MANAGE.

Scheduled jobs are listed with the frequency you specified before migration. On-demand jobs are disabled. To run an on-demand job:

- Select the job you wish to run.
- If necessary, click Enable to enable the job.
- Click Settings, then Schedule.
- Select a Recurrence of Once, then Click Save

Your on-demand jobs are located in App_Data/config/scripts/scheduler post-migration. We recommend that you convert all on-demand jobs to WebJobs or Functions. Write new scheduler jobs as WebJobs or Functions.

For #2, you cannot re-create the service exactly the same way.  The only thing you can do to get the same endpoint is migrate.  If you want to convert your mobile service to something a little more modern, check out Azure Mobile Apps instead.

Comment: if something goes wrong while we migrate to app service using the button below, is there a back up plan?

Comment: We don't switch over the site until everything is working.  If something goes wrong, then the site is reverted back to a Mobile Service and an engineer is automatically informed to look at it.